# Add input-like label to v-card in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image: Select input example]

I want to add a label like a `v-input`'s label to a `v-card` (like in the "select" above).

How can I do this?

I have an idea to append a label via code, but I think it can be done another way.

Comment: What do you mean by label? Do you mean a Title? Label makes sense for input fields as it will be the label describing the field. But a v-card is just a presentation component, a container if you will, that can includes title, subtitle, text and actions.

Comment: I add screenshot to my question

Comment: The screenshot you show seems more like a v-select component and not a v-card.

Comment: And similarly to `v-input`s, `v-select`s have a `label` prop

Comment: yep, I want to add this to my v-card, so my question is how to that

Comment: Not sure I get what you want but as with any other component, you would write something like  `<v-card><v-select label="label"/>...</v-card>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below element to show title in v-card.

```
<v-card-title> Your title here... </v-card-title>
```

Comment: I want to see label in border of v-card, like in the screenshot

Comment: Unfortunately show text on card border is not possible yet.